# C++ template param as base class

Tags: c++, templates

why isnt a derived class not permissioned to access its protected base class member when its templatized?

```
class MyBase {
protected:
    int foo;
};

template<typename Impl>
class Derived : public Impl {
public:
    int getfoo() {
            return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->foo;
    }
};
```

The compiler complains foo is protected. why?

```
error: int MyBase::foo is protected
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are accessing `foo` through an `MyBase*` instead of a `Derived<MyBase>*`. You may only access protected members through your own type, not through the base type.

Try this instead:

```
int getfoo() {
        return this->foo;
}
```

From the C++ 2003 standard, 11.5/1 `[class.protected]`: "When a friend or a member function of a derived class references a protected nonstatic member function or
protected nonstatic data member of a base class … the access must be through a
pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself (or any class derived from that class)"

Comment: or return foo; // an unnecessary comment to make my comment long enough so that stackoverflow let's me post it.

Comment: It should do Rob.  I've got it working in my VS2010 right now :)

Comment: @Robinson: "It works in VS" != "It works in C++". Any compiler strictly following the standard should reject it. When compiling the `Derived` template, the compiler cannot know whether `Impl` contains a member named `foo`, therefore for consistency the standard mandates to not look up an unqualified `foo` in `Impl` (otherwise it would find either a member or a global variable, depending on the template argument). VS2010 obviously doesn't implement that rule correctly (which BTW might cause wrong code to be generated in corner cases).

Comment: @Rob "must be accessed through a pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself" ... reads like the object of the derived class part applies to me.

Comment: @celtschk The compiler can raise an error when the template is instantiated.

Comment: @ScottLangham: I was speaking about what the standard mandates, and why. That other definitions are possible is obvious. But those are not standard conforming, and in corner cases might cause standard-conforming code to be compiled with wrong (i.e. not standard-conforming, and thus possibly not intended) semantics.

Comment: I did try 'code' return foo `code` - didnt work with gcc, casting it atleast lets me find foo, and use if it was public.

Comment: Thanks. I dont recall having this problem in the past - seems weird to me you need a different syntax simply because of different access rules.